# Facebook FBML fb:board troubles

Tags: facebook, fbml

I followed the tutorial on the Facebook dev site and used the following code to create a discussion app. Whenever I click on "Start new Topic" nothing happens. I've searched and found people with similar issues but no one found a solution. Anyone have any idea?

```
<fb:board xid="crockrec_board" 
      canpost="true"
      candelete="false"
      canmark="false"
      cancreatetopic="true"
      numtopics="5"
      returnurl="http: //facebook.com/CrockpotRecipes/">
```

Community Recipes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, there are many problems with this, it's not only you. Even official test console is throwing errors for me. Fill [bug report on their page](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider abandoning any FBML markup like this. FBML is not going to be supported after January 2012 (in about a month) and in June 2012 FBML markup just isn't going to work at all, so anything you write in it now is going to have to be rewritten. Might as well find the alternative now rather than later.